# jquery trigger ctrl + click

Tags: jquery

Just wondering if there is any way to trigger a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + CLICK (or just any key + CLICK) in jQuery. I am thinking of something like the following:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 17;
$('a.'+id, this._parent).trigger(e).trigger('click');
```

or

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('a.'+id, this._parent).trigger(e);
```

Thank you!

Comment: For what purpose? Triggering a click in JS won't fire off a hyperlink, for instance.

Comment: I think it's always better to trigger the RESULT of an action than action itself: change window.location instead of clicking anchor with JS, for example.

Comment: I am using a web control which is a column view (similar to the OSX Finder - see 'http://christianyates.com/comment/1529' for more details). I want to select items in this column view on page load (part of coming back to what the user has selected before) and I am doing this currently by triggering CLICK on elements in the column view. One column can have multiple elements selected and that would be done with CTRL+CLICK. So the why I want to trigger that event.

Comment: [http://christianyates.com/comment/1529] link again.

Comment: Yeah, instead of trying to emulate the click, just add the targets to the set of selected elements.

Comment: Guess the lazy side of me wanted an easy way out. :) Thank you for all your input. Will do what was suggested.

Comment: triggering the result doesn't work if you try to modify a website  behaviour by script injection using Tampermonkey. Also Ctrl+click opens in new tab there might be a 'trigger' solution for that, but basically I want to achieve whatever the configured browser behaviour is for ctrl+click.

Answer (score 21):

yes  this will work for you:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('#id').trigger(e);
```

Comment: I tried this for one of my google chrome extension but couldn't work. Though thanx for raising a hope :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for OSX. I tried `e.metaKey = true` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: It works as oneliner: `$('#id').trigger($.Event("click", { ctrlKey: true }));`

Comment: doesnt work for me (Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit))

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me either - can you give a live example (jsbin or whatever)?

Comment: This was [broken in jQuery 1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987077) _(for a long time, based on the above comments)_.  But I just tried it and it works, so it must be fixed in a recent version.