# simulate ctrl + click with javascript or jquery (to open a new tab without focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing with the jquery event object but I am stuck as hell

I read the API https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ but it's not really helping here, I am not even sure it's a good lead to do that

Do you have any suggestion ( the problem is to do the exact ctrl + click on a link). I saw some posts about it but nothing seems to work on the recent browsers

***very simple exemple :***

```
<span id="toto">toto</span>
<a href="https://google.fr" id="inANewTab"></a>

// The goal is when I click on #toto, I would like #inANewTab trigger 
// in a new tab without focus. To do that I was thinking
// about replicate a ctrl+click event

$('#toto').click(function(){
  ???
})
```

Comment: Maybe have an event listener for the `ctrl` keyboard event, and then within that have a click event to do something?

Comment: @decarte. Were you able to find a solution for "replicate a ctrl+click event"?

Answer (score 8):

Edit:

The Event object in jQuery has a parameter for ctrlKey, you could assign that as true, on click.

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('#id').trigger(e);
```

Reference: [jquery trigger ctrl + click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377046/jquery-trigger-ctrl-click)

Comment: He needs to trigger Ctrl on the keyboard while clicking, not check!

Comment: same (using Chrome)

Answer (score 8):

In pure javascript, you can use the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) for that:

```
document.getElementById("todo").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
```

To programatically open a new tab you can do that:

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com/");
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
```

Comment: This works in Chrome 78 for me, but not Firefox ESR 68. In fact, if ctrlKey is set to true then the click event stops working entirely in FF.

Comment: Not enough jQuery. -1

Comment: @hanshenrik the question asks to provide a solution in javascript *OR* jquery, not both

Comment: https://needsmorejquery.com/

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-jQuery version to simulate keyboard events. This works in both Chrome (WebKit based) and Firefox (Gecko based):

```
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                   "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                    true, // bubbles
                    true, // cancelable
                    window, // viewArg: should be window
                    false, // ctrlKeyArg
                    false, // altKeyArg
                    false, // shiftKeyArg
                    false, // metaKeyArg
                    40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Or using jQuery, you can simulate by jQuery's `event` object:

```
jQuery.event.trigger({
  type:  'keypress',
  which: character.charCodeAt(0)
});
```

Comment: thx for your answer maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I don't really know how to exploit your answer. I edited the question

Comment: @hadesMM Inside your function, add mine. `:)`

Comment: how to do this on a specific element?

Comment: This not only doesn't work for me, it's also deprecated now.

Comment: @Thor84no LoL. You are looking at an answer that was given two years ago. No wonder it is now deprecated.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm aware of that. It's still however top of Google search results and with no decent alternative anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @Thor84no So it didn't work. What about the other answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Opening in a new tab works with either approach, but not in background. I can only assume it's down to pop-under blocking or something, which is a shame since I just want to do it for my own browser (snippets), not to anyone else. I've looked through similar SO questions and none of the answers seem to work anymore.

Comment: @Thor84no It still works with ██████████.com. I hate it when it comes and hides. Will see and let you know.