# Create Ctrl+click mouse event

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to fire a mouse event that would mimic Browser's Ctrl+ mouseclick when clicking on a hyperlink to open a new tab but keep current tab selected. Here is my code:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'URL';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {ctrlKey: true}))
```

It does open a new tab but also switches to it. Any chance to keep it on the currect tab?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simulate ctrl + click with javascript or jquery (to open a new tab without focus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255506/simulate-ctrl-click-with-javascript-or-jquery-to-open-a-new-tab-without-focus)

Comment: They are showing basically same code. Maybe it did work like I want at some point but not anymore.

Comment: did you try `window.open(link.href, '_blank')` instead of dispatching event?

Answer (score 0):

It's default behavior for the browser, you can't change this(

Comment: How is it default when if I do this with a physical click holding Ctrl down it works as I described?

Comment: If you do something then focus going to this action, so when you open new tab then focus for new tab

Comment: Try yourself in the Browser.