# In Intern.js Leadfoot, how do I preform a CTRL Click

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

I'm just wondering what the preferred way to preform a ctrl + click action in leadfoot is. In java I would have used the Actions class and used keyDown, but since we have moved to a JS based framework I'm a complete fish out of water!

I've seen in the api that there is a pressKeys function but it doesn't seem to do what we need. I've thought about using jQuery to do this but I would really rather keep it in the current framework.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pressKeys`, for example:

```
command.moveMouseTo(myBtn)
       .pressKeys(keys.CONTROL)
       .clickMouseButton()
       .pressKeys(keys.CONTROL)
```

A good thing to remember about `pressKeys` (https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#pressKeys)

> keys: The text to type in the remote environment. It is possible to type keys that do not have normal character representations (modifier keys, function keys, etc.) as well as keys that have two different representations on a typical US-ASCII keyboard (numpad keys); use the values from leadfoot/keys to type these special characters. **Any modifier keys that are activated by this call will persist until they are deactivated.** To deactivate a modifier key, type the same modifier key a second time, or send \uE000 ('NULL') to deactivate all currently active modifier keys.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work perfectly! Much appreciated.

Comment: What is `keys` and where is it defined?

Comment: Going to echo Nathan's comment in the hope of getting an answer to this. What is `keys`? Where is it defined? How do you import it into your test?

Comment: keys is a module in leadfoot (https://theintern.io/leadfoot/keys.js.html). You can use it by require("intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/keys")

Answer (score 1):

**TheIntern/LeadFoot** provides you a function `execute`. You can trigger any event from this function using JS.

```
.execute(function() {
    //You can even access window from here
    $("#someId").click() //example

    //or try something like this
    e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
    e.which = 50;
    e.ctrlKey = true;
    $("input").trigger(e);

})
```

To trigger **keyevent** follow these links:

[jquery trigger ctrl + click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377046/jquery-trigger-ctrl-click)

[How to trigger key combo with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893397/how-to-trigger-key-combo-with-jquery)

Comment: Cheers, this does work but we are trying not to bring in jQuery into the framework