# Download multiple files on a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has a many links of files to be downloaded individually. I thought it would be a good to have feature to trigger  download for all the files with a single click. Here's the script which I wrote to test this-

```
$('tbody tr a').slice(1).each(function(){  //don't mind the slice().
    console.log('starting download of: ' + $(this).attr('href')); // for debugging.
    $(this).attr('target','_blank'); //  so that a new page is opened for download.
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
})
```

The problem is that the script only triggers the download of only first download link. However, if I see console, the log is printed for all the files. I think it's happening because of page redirection. Can anyone help me get around this?

Comment: Does `$(this).click()` work?

Comment: Can you try include script on Click of button dynamically?

Comment: @afuous No. I've tried that. This also just logs all the files in console but not starts the download.

Comment: @HardikVaghani: I don't understand what do you mean. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: what do you mean by download ? you want to show script or include in page

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390601/make-multiple-files-to-force-download

Comment: @HardikVaghani: When I click on any of the links, it triggers a file download. I want to start download of all the files without having to click on all the links individually.

Comment: So for that you will have to open multiple links of script

Comment: @hamboy75: The link you are suggesting is very different from my requirement.

Comment: in that question, Miky Dal solution is exactly what you want, multiple downloads on a trigger

Comment: @hamboy75: Firstly, I'm not using PHP. Secondly, I have multiple links on the page, clicking on which downloads a file. I just want to **click** on them with a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting `download` attribute for `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')`, call `.click()` on each `<a>` element within filtered selector `$("tbody tr a").slice(1)` at `.each()` at click of `<button>` element

```js
var a = $("tbody tr a").slice(1);

$("button").click(function(e) {
  // download `a.txt`, `b.txt`
  a.each(function() {
    this.click()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="data:text/plain,1" download="1.txt">1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="data:text/plain,a" download="a.txt">a</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="data:text/plain,b" download="b.txt">b</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- click to download `a.txt`, `b.txt` -->
  <button>download all files</button>
```

Comment: This page doesn't have a `download` attribute defined on links. So I added it by iterating and doing `$(this).attr('target','_blank').attr('download',filename);`. But even after this, `.click()` doesn't start the file download.

Comment: Have you tried  `js` at stacksnippets? Did you call `.click()` chained to `$(this).attr('target','_blank').attr('download',filename)`? Try calling `this.click()` on `DOM` element instead of jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks! the second one, i.e., `this.click()` works. What does this mean though?

Comment: Wait another thing, this only triggered 6 downloads. What about rest of them?

Comment: _"Wait another thing, this only triggered 6 downloads. What about rest of them?"_ What do you mean?

Comment: Got this. There's a setting which limits the maximum number of simultaneous connections to a single server. For my case this is 6 (probably for windows OS).

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this answer here:

[jquery trigger ctrl + click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377046/jquery-trigger-ctrl-click)

Just run on all of your links and trigger ctrl+click in order to open links in new page.

Comment: I've already added `target='_blank'` which essentially has the same effect as **ctrl + click**

Comment: @Abhishek changing window.location and triggering ctrl+click can't be the same, also if it looks same.